# Export CSV tthrough array in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am writing the following code in laravel 8 to put the array in csv and then download it.

```
public function DownloadCustomerCSV(Request $request) {
    $CustomerData = [
        ["firstName" => "test A", "lastName" => "test B"],
        ["firstName" => "test A", "lastName" => "test B"]
    ];
    $columns = array("FirstName", "LastName");
    
    $callback = function() use ($CustomerData, $columns)
    {
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($file, $columns);

        foreach($CustomerData as $Customer) {
            fputcsv($file, array($Customer["firstName"], $Customer["lastName"]));
        }
        fclose($file);
    };
    
    $headers = array(
        "Content-type" => "text/csv",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=customers.csv",
        "Pragma" => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires" => "0"
    );

    return \Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
}
```

This site can’t be reached. The webpage might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Am I missing anything?

Comment: It seems $CustomerData is undefined. Check laravel's error log as well for better clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just replicated this on a fresh install and the only error seems to be with lines 8 and 13 referring to an undefined variable.

If you change `$customerData` to `$customers` on lines 8 and 13 of your code all will work fine.